# C++ Variant: Why does Converting constructor require sizeof...(Types) to be nonzero

Tags: c++, c++17

This question is regarding: `template<class...Types> class variant`:

According to [variant.variant/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.variant#3), a program instantiating `variant` with no template arguments is ill-formed.

So far, so clear. Now I have a question regarding the converting constructor (`template<class T> constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(see below)`):

[variant.variant/variant.ctor-16.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.variant#variant.ctor-16.1) says that the converting constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless:

> sizeof...(Types) is nonzero

(... and some other requirements I do not care about for now).

My question is, when a `variant` with no template arguments already makes my program ill-formed, why still care about whether my converting constructor participates in overload resolution or not?

Having a look at the MSVC and libstdc++ -implementation of `variant` they actually have an `enable_if_t<sizeof...(_Types) != 0>` at the declaration of the converting constructor. Why?

Comment: can you explain use case of variant where there is no variants (even a one)? It is like `0/0` symbol.

Comment: @MarekR that would be the answer to the question.... the question is: why explicitly disable the constructor for a variant wit no variants when anyhow a variant with 0 variants is not allowed

Comment: note that 16.1 is just a "Remark", though still strange that they make that remark...

Comment: @user463035818 remark means required.  It is *note* that is non-normative.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah ok, wasnt sure, just started trying to read the standard ;)

Comment: my wild guess is that you can run into a situation in variadic templates where the fact that this constructor does not participate in overload resolution is the only thing that prevents you from instantiating a `variant` with `sizeof...(Types)` equal to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clause *"sizeof...(Types) is nonzero"* was added to **`[variant.ctor]`** as part of the paper: [Some improvements to class template argument deduction integration into the standard library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0739r0.html) to allow `variant` support as well.

**Relevant Excerpts:**

> **Enable variant support**
>
> The following code fails to compile
>
> ```
> variant<int, double> v1(3);
> variant v2 = v1;  // Ill-formed! <--THIS
> ```
>
> As this natural code is useful and its failure is confusing, we propose that it be supported. Indeed, prior to the adoption of p0510r0 banning `variant<>`, the above code worked as expected since `variant<>` occurs in some deduction guides in the overload set. As it is not clear that constructor template argument deduction was considered in adopting p0510r0, we would like to consider allowing `variant<>` not to produce a hard error in such cases.
>
> **Wording**  (Emphasis added)
>   Change **§23.7.3.1p16 `[variant.ctor]`** as follows:
>   Remarks: This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless **`sizeof...(Types)` is nonzero**, unless `is_same_v<decay_t<T>, variant>` is `false`, unless `decay_t<T>` is neither a specialization of `in_place_type_t` nor a specialization of `in_place_index_t`, unless `is_constructible_v<Tj, T>` is `true`, and unless the expression FUN(std::forward(t)) (with FUN being the above-mentioned set of imaginary functions) is well formed.

So `std::variant v2 = v1;` fails in compiler versions that do not take into account the added clause (like GCC 7.1. See [**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/ufpVF5)) but succeeds on later versions (From GCC 7.2 onwards. See [**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/xm8xMR)).

Comment: As I have less knowledge about CTAD, I do not understand why exactly the clause is necesarry but I understand that CTAD is the reason for the clause. Thanks P.W